# How to attach a file using mail command on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, email

I'm on a server running a Linux shell. 
I need to mail a simple file to a recipient. 
How to do this, prefereably using only the **mail** command?

**UPDATE**: got a good solution, using mutt instead:

```
$ echo | mutt -a syslogs.tar.gz admin@domain.org
```

Comment: The duplicate has an answer of mine which attempts to sort out and clarify the several incompatible versions of `mail`/`mailx` to hopefully make some sense of the multiple conflicting answers here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Example using uuencode:

```
uuencode surfing.jpeg surfing.jpeg | mail sylvia@home.com
```

and reference article:

http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.html

### Note:

you may `apt install sharutils` to have `uuencode` command

Comment: Commentary on http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/postfix/2008-10/0422.html ?

Comment: Is uuencode a "default" GNU tool? My box doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: The reference article was really useful! Thanks!

Comment: @Seiti: uuencode is a part of sharutils, and it is GNU software. Ubuntu package is called sharutils, too. http://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/

Comment: This works only for recipients which allow uuencoded attachments

Comment: On ubuntu, the following will install uuencode and mail (respectively): sudo apt-get install sharutils; sudo apt-get install mailutils

Comment: This is a good workaround for an ecosystem which is stuck in the early 1990s but the preferred solution in the modern world is to switch to MIME. The solution with `mutt` does that nicely and reasonably portably.

Comment: If you wish to have an attachment AND text in the body, here is a similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315149/2657515

Answer (score 23):

`mail` on every version of modern Linux that I've tried can do it. No need for other software:

```
matiu@matiu-laptop:~$ mail -a doc.jpg someone@somewhere.com
Subject: testing

This is a test
EOT
```

ctrl+d when you're done typing.

Comment: Not really accurate.  There are versions of `mail` which support this, but they are certainly not "plain old `mail`" but rather, some modernized version or variant. It would help if you specify which version you are using, on which platform.

Comment: This is on ubuntu 14.04 using Heirloom mailx version 12.5 6/20/10. From memory, it also works on centos 6, ubuntu 12.04 and centos 7.

Comment: i was able to do this in interactive mode, I was wondering if there is a script version of this?

Comment: To make it not require user interaction: echo This is a test | mail -a doc.jpg -s "testing" someone@somewhere.com

Comment: Worked with RHEL6.8  mail ver: 12.4 7/29/08

Comment: The mailutils version of mail uses `-A` for attachments (GNU Mailutils 2.99.99 on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Server)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line/48588035#48588035 now has an overview of different `mail` heritages which II had originally posted as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 22):

```
$ echo | mutt -a syslogs.tar.gz admin@domain.org
```

But it uses mutt, not mail (or mailx).

Comment: Did not QUITE work for me.  Order of arguments was different.  What worked was: `echo | mutt admin@domain.org -a syslogs.tar.gz`.  I am using mutt version 1.5.20.

Comment: It works for me to send log from unix to mail server.  Thanks

Answer (score 13):

[mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html) might help as well.  From the mailx man page:

```
-a file
     Attach the given file to the message.
```

Pretty easy, right?

Comment: note that this is not the mailx in Ubuntu. Using that one, `-a` means `Specify additional header fields on the command line such as "X-Loop: foo@bar" etc.  You have to use quotes if the string
             contains spaces.  This argument may be specified more than once, the headers will then be concatenated.`

Comment: My `mailx` doesn't support `-a` (package mailx-8.1.1-44.2.2 on CentOS)

Comment: Mine doesn't support `-a` either (OS X 10.7.5)

Answer (score 12):

My answer needs base64 in addition to mail, but some uuencode versions can also do base64 with -m, or you can forget about mime and use the plain uuencode output...

```
   FROM=me@mydomain.com
   TO=someone@mydomain.com
   SUBJECT="Auto emailed"
   MIME="application/x-gzip"  # Adjust this to the proper mime-type of file
   FILE=somefile.tar.gz
   ENCODING=base64  
   boundary="---my-unlikely-text-for-mime-boundary---$$--" 

   (cat <<EOF
    From: $FROM
    To: $REPORT_DEST
    Subject: $SUBJECT
    Date: $(date +"%a, %b %e %Y %T %z")
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="$boundary"
    Content-Disposition: inline

    --$boundary
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
    Content-Disposition: inline

    This email has attached the file

    --$boundary
    Content-Type: $MIME;name="$FILE"
    Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="$FILE"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: $ENCODING

    EOF
    base64 $FILE
    echo ""
    echo "--$boundary" ) | mail
```

Comment: For some reason when using mutt, encrypted attachments would grow by 400-500% when encoded which basically limited me to ~2MB attachments. So I had to build the email from scratch with a base64 encoded attachment using this method, except I'm sure you meant to pipe it to `sendmail -t` instead.

Comment: Nice answer - I like the cat append part.

Comment: This is nice if you don't have access to proper MIME tools, but piecing together the MIME structure by hand gets tired fast. If you have more than a one-off need, you probably want to find a tool which encapsulates these steps for you.

Comment: And that's assuming your `mail` doesn't choke on MIME input, but you  can just switch to `| sendmail -oi -t` at the end of the pipeline in that case; you don't need any of the features that the `mail` wrapper offers you any longer at this point.

Comment: The final line should have `echo "--$boundary--"` before the closing parenthesis, with two dashes at the end to mark this as the final, closing boundary.

Comment: The `Content-Disposition: inline` is RFC-correct but apparently problematic for Yahoo (but then what isn't); it's perfectly optional anyway, so maybe just take it out if that's a consideration. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436217/mutt-on-linux-has-empty-text-attachments-that-appear-in-yahoo-mail

Answer (score 7):

```
mailx -a /path/to/file email@address
```

You might go into interactive mode (it will prompt you with "Subject: " and then a blank line), enter a subject, then enter a body and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (EOT) to finish.

Comment: On Mac 10.7 I get an error doing this. `mailx: illegal option -- a`

Comment: that's because OSX doesn't have lots of the modern updated CLI utilities like linux has. use homebrew or macports to install coreutils

Comment: @f0ster `mailx` is not part of GNU coreutils.  You can probably find a version of `mailx` for OSX which supports this usage, but without a link to one, this isn't really helpful at all. There are multiple versions, many of which do not support this usage.

Answer (score 4):

```
mpack -a \
    -s"Hey: might this serve as your report?" \
    -m 0 -c application/x-tar-gz \
    survey_results.tar.gz \
    hesco@example.net
```

`mpack` and `munpack` work together with `metamail` to extend `mailx`
and make it useful with modern email cluttered with HTML markup and attachments.

Those four packages taken together will permit you to handle
any email you could in a GUI mail client.

Comment: This worked for me, nothing else seemed to work on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Unfortunately, the metamail package which contined these utilities has been abandoned and is now very hard to find. You are probably better off with a modern MIME client anyway; these old utilities were provided as a baseline demonstration when MIME was new, but they were never very versatile or easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Using ubuntu 10.4, this is how the mutt solution is written

`echo | mutt -a myfile.zip -- admin@domain.org`

Comment: Same for `mutt` from Homebrew

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers here using mutt or mailx or people saying mail doesn't support "-a"

First, Ubuntu 14.0.4 mail from mailutils supports this:

mail -A filename -s "subject" email@example.com

Second, I found that by using the "man mail" command and searching for "attach"

Answer (score 1):

The following is a decent solution across Unix/Linux installations, that does not rely on any unusual program features. This supports a multi-line message body, multiple attachments, and all the other typical features of `mailx`.

Unfortunately, it does not fit on a single line.

```
#!/bin/ksh

# Get the date stamp for temporary files
DT_STAMP=`date +'%C%y%m%d%H%M%S'`

# Create a multi-line body
echo "here you put the message body
which can be split across multiple lines!
woohoo!
" > body-${DT_STAMP}.mail

# Add several attachments
uuencode File1.pdf File1.pdf >  attachments-${DT_STAMP}.mail
uuencode File2.pdf File2.pdf >> attachments-${DT_STAMP}.mail

# Put everything together and send it off!
cat body-${DT_STAMP}.mail attachments-${DT_STAMP}.mail > out-${DT_STAMP}.mail
mailx -s "here you put the message subject" nobody@test-address.com < out-${DT_STAMP}.mail

# Clean up temporary files
rm body-${DT_STAMP}.mail
rm attachments-${DT_STAMP}.mail
rm out-${DT_STAMP}.mail
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315149/2657515

Answer (score 0):

With mailx you can do:

```
mailx -s "My Subject"  -a ./mail_att.csv -S from=noreply@foo.com  recipient@bar.com < ./mail_body.txt
```

This worked great on our GNU Linux servers, but unfortunately my dev environment is Mac OsX which only has a crummy old BSD version of mailx. Normally I use Coreutils to get better versions of unix commands than the Mac BSD ones, but mailx is not in Coreutils.

I found a solution from notpeter in an unrelated thread (https://serverfault.com/questions/196001/using-unix-mail-mailx-with-a-modern-mail-server-imap-instead-of-mbox-files) which was to download the Heirloom mailx OSX binary package from http://www.tramm.li/iWiki/HeirloomNotes.html.
It has a more featured mailx which can handle the above command syntax.

(Apologies for poor cross linking linking or attribution, I'm new to the site.)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux I would suggest,

# FILE_TO_BE_ATTACHED=abc.gz

```
uuencode abc.gz abc.gz > abc.gz.enc # This is optional, but good to have
                                    # to prevent binary file corruption.
                                    # also it make sure to get original 
                                    # file on other system, w/o worry of endianness

# Sending Mail, multiple attachments, and multiple receivers.
echo "Body Part of Mail" | mailx -s "Subject Line" -a attachment1 -a abc.gz.enc "youremail@domain.com anotheremail@domain.com"
```

Upon receiving mail attachment, if you have used uuencode, you would need uudecode

```
uudecode abc.gz.enc
```

# This will generate file as original with name as same as the 2nd argument for uuencode.

Comment: If you have a `mailx` which supports `-a` for including MIME attachments, there is absolutely no need to separately `uuencode` them. Attaching will wrap the content in a suitable content transfer encoding like `base64` if necessary -- this is in fact *more* portable and robust than `uuencode`, as well as decidedly a lot more usable.

Answer (score 0):

I use [mailutils](https://mailutils.org/) and the confusing part is that in order to attach a file you need to use the capital A parameter. below is an example.

```
echo 'here you put the message body' | mail -A syslogs.tar.gz admin@domain.org
```

If you want to know if your mail command is from mailutils just run "mail -V".

```
root@your-server:~$ mail -V
mail (GNU Mailutils) 2.99.98
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```