# Sending simple message body + file attachment using Linux Mailx

Tags: shell, mailx

I am writing a `shell script` to send an email using Linux `Mailx`, the email must contain a **file attachment** and a **message body**.

Currently sending an email with an attachment:

```
output.txt | mail -s "Daily Monitoring" james@dell.com
```

I wish to add a message body. How should i?

Linux Mailx:

```
mail [-eIinv] [-a header] [-b addr] [-c addr] [-s subj] to-addr
```

Comment: This should have all the answers to your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line/14213935#14213935

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The usual way is to use [`uuencode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) for the attachments and `echo` for the body:

```
(uuencode output.txt output.txt; echo "Body of text") | mailx -s 'Subject' user@domain.com
```

---

*For Solaris and AIX, you may need to put the `echo` statement first:*

```
(echo "Body of text"; uuencode output.txt output.txt) | mailx -s 'Subject' user@domain.com
```

Comment: tried executing the second one and it prompts a blank area and the only way to exit is ctr+c, it seems the code is not close, how can i solve this?

Comment: and when I press ctrl+c, it sends the mail without the attachment, please advise.

Comment: Do each of these commands in the pipeline work on your system individually?

Comment: @Johnsyweb-I need to do the same activity without using uuencode. Is it possible??

Comment: @nikhil: There are several alternatives here https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359/78845

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use mpack!

mpack -s "Subject" -d "./body.txt" "././image.png" mailadress

mpack - subject - body - attachment - mailadress

Answer (score 1):

Johnsyweb's answer didn't work for me, but it works for me with Mutt:

```
echo "Message body" | mutt -s "Message subject" -a myfile.txt recipient@domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works for me:

```sh
(echo "Hello XYX" ; uuencode /export/home/TOTAL_SI_COUNT_10042016.csv TOTAL_SI_COUNT_10042016.csv ) | mailx -s 'Script test' abc@xde.com
```

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL Linux, I had trouble getting my message in the body of the email instead of as an attachment .   Using od -cx, I found that the body of my email contained several /r.   I used a perl script to strip the /r, and the message was correctly inserted into the body of the email.

```
mailx -s "subject text" me@yahoo.com < 'body.txt'
```

The text file body.txt contained the char \r, so I used perl to strip \r.

```
cat body.txt | perl success.pl > body2.txt
mailx -s "subject text" me@yahoo.com < 'body2.txt'
```

This is success.pl

```
    while (<STDIN>) {
        my $currLine = $_;
        s?\r??g;
        print
    }
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(cat ./body.txt)|mailx -s "subject text" -a "attchement file" receiver@domain.com
```