# How to send mail from linux command line with HTML content body and an attachment

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I need to send mail from a linux host with HTML content type and also attach a file to the mail.

```
cat html_mail.txt

To: me@mydomain.com

Subject: Test Mail

Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

Content-Disposition: inline

<span style="background-color:green">This is in green</span>
```

I tried the below options:

```
mail: 

mail -a attachment_file < html_mail.txt
```

"mail" command sends an attachment but the HTML content in html_mail.txt is coming up as plain text in the mail

```
Execution of the command says "Ignoring headers Content-Type".

sendmail:
cat html_mail.txt |sendmail -t
sendmail sends the html content properly, but I couldn't find an option to send an attachment.
```

Comment: I don't have uuencode on my host

Comment: how this can be OFF-TOPIC question??????

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314999/sending-simple-message-body-file-attachment-using-linux-mailx

Answer (score 3):

### Sending "HTML only" email using low level `sendmail` command

1) Add necessary MIME headers
([`MIME-Version`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/3_MIME-Version.html), [`Content-Type`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html), [`Content-Transfer-Encoding`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html))

html_mail_file

```
To: me@mydomain.com
Subject: Test Mail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT
Content-Disposition: inline

<span style="background-color:green">This is in green</span>
```

*For non `us-ascii` charsets declare `8BIT` encoding.  Most email servers will conduct necessary transformations of "raw" 8BIT encoding.

2) Send it using `sendmail` program

```
/usr/bin/sendmail -i -t < html_mail_file
```

or if you prefer to keep email headers separately

```
echo | cat email_headers_file - html_file | /usr/bin/sendmail -i -t
```

Comment: Yes, tried that. Didn't help. thanks