# how to include HTML code in Mailx mail body

Tags: unix

How can i send the email using mailx command including the HTML code?
for example:

```
mailx -s "Report" << EOF
Report Generated
<table width="600">
<tr><td width="30%">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td width="35%" style="font-size:7pt;">Definition</td></tr></table>EOF
```

however the mail did send, but which is not as html code..

Anybody know how to send mailx including the html inside the mail body?

Comment: Use sendmail instead, as defined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line/14213935#14213935

Answer (score 7):

I havent used mailx for sending HTML but have used sendmail.
You can use the following if you can use sendmail instead of mailx

```
(echo -e "Subject: $SUBJECT\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nFrom: $MAIL_FROM\nTo:$MAIL_TO\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Disposition: inline\n\n";/bin/cat $MAIL_FILE) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f  $MAIL_FROM $MAIL_TO
```

I tried this on Linux

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. I guess it just can't be done with mailx.

Answer (score 0):

mailx allows you to specify additional headers with the -a option.
So you can use something as `mailx  -a "Content-Type: text/html"`.

Comment: This option actually attaches a file.

Comment: @Rajish -A attaches a file.

Answer (score 0):

the -a "Content-Type..." works with mailx on Ubuntu.

Comment: Not as of now. Mailx `-a` adds a file. It says `Content-Type: text/html: No such file or directory`