# Sending multiple files as attachment in Unix mail command

Tags: unix, mailx

I have one piece of code which is mentioned below where it's sending two files as attachment.

```
mailx  -s "$ms - $cdate $ctime" $ReportGroup < ${mailmsg} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Here mailmsg contents some files. Now i am trying to send one more file `xyz.csv` in the above command.
how can i do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the contents of `xyz.csv` to `${mailmsg}` before the `mailx` invocation, with proper formatting/structure so that it appears to be another attachment... How is the existing `${mailmsg}` being created? Find that and copy the pattern.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line/4887607#4887607

Answer (score 0):

use uuuencode function something like

(uuencode filename.format filename_to_be_dispalyed_in_attachment.format)|mailx- s "subject"  ${mailmsg} >/dev/null 2>&1