# Bash script sending an e-mail with attachment, body and subject

Tags: bash, email, attachment

I am doing a MySQL database backup script and I would like it to report to me via e-mail.

So far I was able to make it to have a subject and a body without attachment. Code:

```
cat << EOF | mail -s "MySQL backups for $(date +%d.%m.%Y\ %H:%M)" mymail@mydomain.com
'text in the body'
text outside of the quotes
$value
EOF
```

Also separately than the above, I was able to make it to send e-mail with subject and attachment, but without body. Code:

```
gzip -c test.sh | uuencode test.sh.gz | mail -s "MySQL backups for $(date +%d.%m.%Y\ %H:%M)" mymail@mydomain.com
```

When I try to combine them as below, I am receiving an e-mail with an empty body.

```
cat << EOF | gzip -c test.sh | uuencode test.sh.gz | mail -s "MySQL backups for $(date +%d.%m.%Y\ %H:%M)" mymail@mydomain.com
'text in the body'
text outside of the quotes
$value
EOF
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the piped command, you override the body of the message with the encoding of attachment.

try something like:

```
cat << EOF | mail -s "MySQL backups for $(date +%d.%m.%Y\ %H:%M)" mymail@mydomain.com
'text in the body'
text outside of the quotes
$value

$(gzip -c test.sh | uuencode test.sh.gz)
EOF
```

Comment: Fantastic! It works as expected. 

Now I may need to find out how to do the same thing without archiving the file... it will be greatly appreciated if you could still help.

Comment: Are you archiving to a file? `gzip -c` writes to standard output, not `test.sh.gz`, and since the standard input of `uuencode` is connected to the output of `gzip` via the pipe, it is ignoring the file name you give it as an argument.

Comment: Well I tried with `$(gzip -c test.sh | uuencode test.sh)` and it sent me a file, but it was not readable. 

I tried with `$(test.sh)` but it did not attach anything.  

I also tried with `$test.sh` but it did not attach anything.