# How do I send a file as an attachment in bash script using sendmail?

Tags: bash, shell, sendmail, attachment

I'm using bash script.  I want to send an email with sendmail, using one file as the body and adding another file as an attachment.  How do I do this?  I have figured out how to send the first file as the email body ...

```
#Send the email
cat - $TFILE1 <<END | /usr/sbin/sendmail -- $to_email
Subject: $subject
To: $to_email

END
```

but I can't figure out how I would adjust the above to include a second file (say that its stored in $TFILE2), as an attachment?

Comment: `sendmail` by itself doesn't have any attachment option. Try one of the alternatives listed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223636/sendmail-attachment

Comment: I'm stunned ... it is impossible to send an attachment with sendmail?

Comment: `sendmail` isn't really an email client, it is a routing service. See http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usendmai.htm

Comment: Is it text/html/binary file?

Comment: THe file I want to attach is a text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use `uuencode` to send attachments, but with `mailx` (I've never used `sendmail` before). To use `uuencode` you'll need to install `sharutils`.

The syntax with `uuencode` and `mailx` is as follows:

```
uuencode attachment.txt attachment.txt | mailx -s "$subject" "$to_email"
```

Comment: I'm using Amazon Liniux.  Is there a way to install yoru suggestion without building it from scratch (e.g. a package I can install)?  The environment I'm on doesn't have all the development tools set up.

Comment: I've never used Amazon Linux, but you could try `sudo yum install sharutils`?

Comment: Hey how would I expand this to send an email with a body and an attachment?

Comment: You could try: `(echo "body text"; uuencode attachment.txt attachment.txt) | mailx -s "$subject" "$to_email"`