# How to send email with attachment in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, email-attachments

I am trying to send an email with 2 attachment by running a shell script. Below is the code:

```
echo "hi attached is the xml file requested.regards Team."| mailx -a this/is/the/path/tools/v2/xml/bad_out/0106_out.xml,this/is/the/path/tools/v2/xml/bad_out/0107_out.xml muc@tm.com,ti@b.com
```

Below is the error i am getting:

```
mail: invalid option -- a
Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...
            [-- sendmail-options ...]
       mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
       mail [-iInNv] [-u user]
```

I also tried same code with just one attachment and it is still giving me the same error.I also want the body to not be in a single line but be in this format :

```
Hi
Attached is the xml file as requested.
Regards
Team.
```

Comment: Mutt can send email with attachment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [send email with attachment using Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143562/send-email-with-attachment-using-unix)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command:

```
echo -e "Hi\nAttached is the xml file as requested.\nRegards,\nTeam" | mailx -s "Attachments" -a file1 -a file2 example@domain.com
```

Comment: I tried the command above and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: That's odd. I tried on Linux 7 and it worked perfectly fine for me.