# Send mail with attachment using sendmail on linux

Tags: linux, email, centos, sendmail

I want to send a mail with attachment from linux command line using sendmail utility.

Here's the command, I am running from terminal on linux machine.

```
sendmail -f ru@gmail.com -t sm67@gmail.com -m "testing the attachement using sendmail unix" -a AnnualReport.docx
```

But this command is not sending mail. Can someone share the appropriate command. I have to use sendmail utility only.

Comment: are you able to use sendmail to send a test email without attachments?  If not, chances are- sendmail is not configured correctly.  You may want to refer to this blogpost about configuring sendmail to work from "localhost":  https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/configure-sendmail-centos  Otherwise, refer to the CentOS Sendmail documentation at: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s3-email-mta-sendmail-default.html

Comment: sendmail is configured properly, Pragmatically I am able to send mail using sendmail. But through terminal, i am facing problem. May be some syntax issue.

Comment: `-m` and `-a` are not supported by canonical sendmail (sendmail by sendmail.org).  Name "sendmail look alike" you use.

Comment: @AnFi Can you please share the correct command?

Comment: Search a little for many solutions/recipe provided at the site e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line

Comment: @AnFi In the link which you have shared, mutt command is used. I have already specified in my question that I want send mail using sendmail utility only.