# BCC not working properly with mail command

Tags: linux, email, centos, mailx

I am attempting to send an e-mail to a recipient and bcc two other address using th e mail command. The issue is that the "-b " flag is not being read as such leading mail to try sending an e-mail to " -b someone@example.com ". The command is shown below.

```
mail -s "Test" person1@example.com -b person2@example.com </dev/null
```

Comment: What works and what doesn't depends on the precise version of `mail`. Please [edit] your question to provide more details about your `mail` (or `mailx`? The question says `mail` but you tagged it [tag:mailx]) package version and ideally some identifying characteristics from its local `man` page. For an overview of exactly how messy this is, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588035/874188

Comment: If this is accurate, you have Heirloom `mailx`: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/mailx

Answer (score 0):

Traditional Unix tools generally prefer their options *before* any non-option arguments, not mixed freely as some other conventions allow.

```
mail -s "Test" -b person2@example.com person1@example.com</dev/null
```

The *SYNOPSIS* section of the [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/nail/) spells this out.