# Send a dump that is exported from a remote server to an email

Tags: ssh

I already connected to remote server and exported that dump by this command "**mysqldump -u user-p dbname > dump.sql**" and now i want to send it through email and all these through SSH ... any help ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Just a short one-liner:

```
ssh host "mysqldump -u user -p dbname >dump.sql &&
gzip -9 dump.sql &&
mailx -s sqldump -a dump.sql.gz recipient@some.domain </dev/null"
```