# Sending e-mail from bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, smtp, msmtp

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, GNU Mailutils 3.4 and MSMTP 1.6.6 to send an e-mail, containing an attachment, from a Bash script (and/or testing from the command line). I was using BSD-Mailx when the server was running 16.04, but upgrading to 18.04 caused Mailx to not be able to send attachments.

I have tried multiple formats of the `mail` command in order to pass text to the body of the e-mail, yet they all seem to fail. Some examples:

```
echo "This is the body of the e-mail" | mail address@example.com -s "This is the subject" -A /file/path/file.txt
```

All I get is the attached file with an empty e-mail.

```
mail address@example.com -s "This is the subject" -A /file/path/file.txt <<< echo "This is the body of the e-mail"
```

Again, empty e-mail with the attachment.

I have also tried it with the e-mail address at the end of the command, which still just gives an empty e-mail with the attachment.

I have tried several other iterations of the above, such as a single `<` redirect, `|` the text at the end of the command, which of course fail, but just trying to guess at the correct format.

Does anyone else have this figured this out?

Comment: If you run `mail` without redirection, you may see that it prompts for `Cc:`. Perhaps your message body has ended up in that header.

Comment: I have looked through the headers and don't see any of the text that was provided for the message body. I would think that I would receive an "undeliverable" response if my text was inserted in the CC: line since the text isn't a valid e-mail addres.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359/7552 -- full disclosure, I have an answer there I'm proud of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### using mailutils

I think the problem is that if you specify `-A`, stdin is ignored: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54992

You can include the body text as an additional attachment:

```
echo "This is the body of the e-mail" |\
mail address@example.com \
    -s "This is the subject" \
    --skip-empty-attachments \
    --content-type text/plain -A - \
    -A /file/path/file.txt
```

### using mutt

Although I don't think mutt is really intended for scripting, it looks like this should work:

```
echo "this is the body" |\
mutt \
  -s "this is the subject" \
  -a /file/path/file.txt -- \
  address@example.com
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct; I didn't think to test without the attachment. Plus, sending the text of the e-mail as an attachment works...but isn't very useful. It is strange to me that this worked before with BSD-Mailx, but apparently an "upgrade" of that application changed the -a/-A function from attaching files to adding headers(?). I was hoping that a switch to Mailutils would do what I needed, but apparently not. And I have tried Mutt, but not as simple as I was hoping.

Comment: If you have a multipart mime message, I believe every body part is an attachment. I've updated the answer to avoid the empty first attachment that was being added.

Comment: `mime-construct` appears to exist in ports

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jhnc I for pointing me to https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54992. I posted my issue there and received a response that this was a bug which has now been fixed in Mailutils 3.5-3 according to this discussion https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918806#22.

There is a workaround, in the meantime, by adding the `--mime` attribute, like so:

```
echo "body text" | /usr/bin/mail --mime -s "some subject" -A "somefile.csv" my@email.com
```

Apparently, I need some work on my 'Google foo' and Stackoverflow participation. And I hope this is the "right" way to respond to my original question.