# Behavior of sending email with text and attachment changed in Ubuntu 20.04 for mail from mailutils

Tags: bash, email

In Ubuntu 16.04 I used the following command to send an email with text and attachements, which worked fine.

```
echo "body" | mail -s "Subject" -A "/path/to/attachment" "email@adress"
```

In Ubuntu 20.04 this command attaches the body-part as an attachment too. The mail --version is 3.7.

Sending only the attachments or only the body is working fine.

This question is about mail from mailutils not mutt nor mailx nor sendmail, etc.
A solution is very very welcome. Thx a lot!

Comment: Please define "worked fine".

Comment: Worked fine: The mail was send and showed the text "body" as mail content and an attached file named "attachment". Now in 20.04 the mail is empty but have a second attachment which holds the word "body" which is named differently when viewed over differend email clients.

Comment: Probably a bug. Version 3.11.1 in debian sets `Content-Disposition: inline` as expected. Ubuntu 20.04 has 3.7.

Comment: I confirm that I use mail version 3.7  What would you do? Reporting the issue, but whom? Installing 3.11.1 if possible??? Or a version between? Or is there a way to tell mail explicit to use one part inline? Or what else? Thx for your advise in advance.

Comment: debian bug [940249](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=940249)
refers to 
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/mailutils.git/commit/?id=3a15565050 which appears to have been applied with release-3.9-7. You could report to ubuntu I guess.

Comment: If you are willing to use mutt, you could try https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202457/10971581 . Ubuntu also has `mime-construct`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to @jhnc for all the information!

This behavior is a bug in mail 3.7 in the package mailutils and adressed in launchpad by
[1911894](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mailutils/+bug/1911894).

**But as of today it is unassigned! Not likely to be changed soon.**

But Ubuntu 20.04 is a LTS version and sending mail with text and attachements is quite common these days.

If you come along and have the same problem, please fill in a bug report, which is quit easy and helps to increase the importance.

To generate a bug report run in a terminal

`apport-cli mailutils`

and send it with `S` to launchpad.

Open browser with `1` and login.

Then enter `1911894` to find the inital bug thread and join. THX!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple 'solution' is to install the latest mailutils-3.15. This issue is fixed as I verified.
Download link:
https://mailutils.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to @onemorequestion's answer, I found a workaround in the [mailing list](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918806#22) for the bug:

> you can use the `--mime` option as a workaround:
>
> ```
> echo "body text" | /usr/bin/mail --mime -s "some subject" -A "somefile.csv" my@email.com
> ```

This adds the body text as an attachment, but it's better than nothing!

Answer (score -1):

Attachement with uuencode works fine with UB20.04

```
( cat body-message.txt; uuencode input-attachment.txt output-attachment.txt ) \
| mail -s "Email With Body Text and Attachment" ****@gmail.com
```

Comment: It's 2022, uuencode should absolutely not be used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @tripleee Agreed !  but when we use the -A option in mail, email body also coming as a attachment.

Comment: That depends on the `mail` version; there are multiple incompatible implementations. See perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line/48588035#48588035