# How to send mail with attachment using shell

Tags: shell, email, scripting

I am trying to `sending mail` with attachment using `shell script`, but I am not getting mail.

**Shell Script**

```
 #!/bin/bash

 $ echo "Mail Sent" | mail -s "a subject" -a "Report_by_Customer_20190614_131246.xls" test@gmail.com
```

Comment: not getting message at all, or not getting the attachment? `-a ...` is not the right way to attach files

Answer (score 0):

Use `mutt`. Add list of files that you want to attach

```
echo "body" | mutt -s "subject" -a attachment0 attachment1 [...] -- test@gmail.com
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line) you can find another options