# Inserting the date into a "MAIL" message body in a BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, email, debian-stretch

I have a relatively simple BASH script to send mail from my Raspberry Pi.  The first argument is the Subject line and the second is a string of data files to be attached.

It is basically working when I specify the message body as a file (line 6).  But if I try to create a text sting containing the date as the message body it fails (line7).  Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo $2
# To
TO="me@hotmail.com"
# Message
MESSAGE="output/MessageBody.txt"
MESSAGEx="Midnight `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` Pi report"
echo $MESSAGE
echo $MESSAGEx

temp=$(echo $2 | tr ";" "\n")
declare -a attargs
for att in $temp; do
  attargs+=( "-A"  "$att" )
done
# Sending email using /bin/mail
/usr/bin/mail -s "$1" "$TO" ${attargs[@]}  < $MESSAGEx
```

Here is the output from this command

```
/usr/pgms/sendtome.sh "test message" "/mnt/usbdrive/output/JSONstart.txt;/mnt/usbdrive/output/Outback_error.log;/mnt/usbdrive/output/OutbackReaderPrint.txt"
```

when I specify MESSAGEx as the message body:

> /mnt/usbdrive/output/MessageBody.txt
>
> Midnight 2019-08-14 07:40:31 MDT Pi report
>
> /usr/pgms/sendtome.sh: line 22: $MESSAGEx: ambiguous redirect

If I use MESSAGE, ie the text file reference, it works.
How can it create a message body text paragraph which contains the date or some other item? Thanks....RDK

Comment: thanks, I already look at the reference and di not find it useful.  Here is the command line I'm using to test: /usr/pgms/sendtome.sh "test message" "/output/JSONstart.txt;/output/error.log;/output/ReaderPrint.txt"

Comment: also that reference seems to be addressing the use of MAILX, while I'm using MAIL.  Not sure of the differences??

Comment: They are essentially the same command. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588035/874188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of issues here.

- You should generally [quote strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) Without quoting, the string after `<` is split (hence the error message) and the array you took so much care to collect will lose its purpose.
- The thing after `<` needs to be the name of a file. In Bash you can use a here string `<<<"$MESSAGEx"` but the common and simple portable solution is to `echo` (or better `printf`) its value into a pipe.
- You should prefer lower case for your private variable names, but this is mainly a stylistic recommendation. (There are reserved variables like `PATH` and `SHELL` which you really don't want to clobber; POSIX reserves upper case variable names for system use.)

Here's a refactoring which attempts to address these concerns.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
to="me@hotmail.com"
# Message
#msgfile="output/MessageBody.txt"
msgbody="Midnight `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` Pi report"
#echo "$msgfile"
#echo "$msgbody"

declare -a attargs
for att in $(echo "$2" | tr ";" "\n"); do
  attargs+=( "-A"  "$att" )
done

/usr/bin/mail -s "$1" "${attargs[@]}" "$to"<<< "$msgbody"
```

Perhaps a better design would be to just `shift` the first argument and then use `"$@"` as the list of files to attach.