# Sending mail Body and attachment using mailx - Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail, mutt, mailx

```
mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' \
      -s "Body" \
  < index.html "foo@example.com"
```

I'm trying to send an email using a `mailx` command line. The above command is working fine to send body as html file.
But along with it I also want to send an attachment.
Is it possible to send an attachment and body as a file together?
How to do it?

Comment: What works in `mailx` depends on which version you are talking about. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588035/874188 has an exposition of this Tower of Babel.

Comment: There's a limit to how complex MIME structures it makes sense to specify serially on the command line. This is approaching the point where a small Python script might start to look like a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using `mutt`.
Here is the command:

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" \
     -s "Your subject" to@domain.com \
     -a attachfile.txt < index.html
```

The content in the file `index.html` will be shown in the body of the mail.
You can attach any number of attachments with `-a <file1> <file2>`

Comment: Probably each separate attachment will need a separate `-a` option, like `-a file1 -a file2`