# Ubuntu mailx attach file without the whole path as the filename

Tags: email, ubuntu, system-administration, mailx

I use the below command to send emails in an Ubuntu server. This seems to attach the testreport.csv file with its full path as the filename.

```
 echo "This email is a test email" | mailx -s 'Test subject' testemail@gmail.com -A "/home/dxduser/reports/testreport.csv"
```

How can I stop this from happening? Is it possible to attach the file with its actual name? In this case "testreport.csv"?

I use mailx (GNU Mailutils) 3.7 version on Ubuntu 20.04

EDIT: Could someone please explain why I got downvoted for this question?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed version information; I was able to verify with `mailutils` on 20.04 that it indeed puts the full path in the `Content-Disposition:` header. I would report this as a bug to the maintainer.

Comment: That would be great! In the meantime, as I replied to your answer, I'll use mutt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [multiple different `mailx` implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line/48588035#48588035) around, so what exactly works will depend on the version you have installed.

However, as a quick and dirty workaround, you can temporarily `cd` into that directory (provided you have execute access to it):

```
(  cd /home/dxduser/reports
   echo "This email is a test email" |
   mailx -s 'Test subject' testemail@gmail.com -A testreport.csv
)
```

The parentheses run the command in a subshell so that the effect of the `cd` will only affect that subshell, and the rest of your program can proceed as before.

I would regard it as a bug if your `mailx` implementation puts in a `Content-Disposition:` with the full path of the file in the filename.

An alternative approach would be to use a different client. If you can't install e.g. `mutt`, creating a simple shell script wrapper to build the MIME structure around a `base64` or `quoted-printable` encoding of your CSV file is not particularly hard, but you have to know what you are doing. In very brief,

```
( cat <<\:
Subject: test email
Content-type: text/csv
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="testreport.csv"
From: me <myself@example.org>
To: you <recipient@example.net>
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

:
base64 </home/dxduser/reports/testreport.csv
) | /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t
```

where obviously you have to have `base64` and `sendmail` installed, and probably tweak the path to `sendmail` (or just omit it if it's in your `PATH`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @tripleee . I decided to go ahead with mutt. It seems to have fixed my issue.