# How to set sender name in mailutils while preserving the sender address

Tags: email, ubuntu, smtp, postfix-mta

I have set up mailutils in ubuntu 20.04, I can send an email using the command below

`echo 'this is a body' | mail -s 'Test Email' -r noreply@domain.com myaddress@example.com`

but the first problem with the above command is that it sends the mail with the name 'Ubuntu', which is my current user, only the sender name is not good in this case, the sender address is the one I specified. (`Ubuntu <noreply@domain.com>`).

Then in this second command when I try to send specifying the sender's name:

`echo 'this is a body' | mail -s 'Test Email' -r 'SenderName <noreply@domain.net>' myaddress@example.com`

In my email inbox it will show the following sender: `Ubuntu <SenderName@mainmailserver-1-eu>`

How can I change the sender name in mailutils while preserving the sender address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-r` option sets the *envelope* sender. Probably try

```
mailx -s 'Test Email' -a 'From: SenderName <noreply@domain.net>' myaddress@example.com <<<"this is a body"
```

You may wish to *also* separately set the envelope sender, but this adds a proper `From:` header which controls what gets displayed more directly.

Some MUAs might still display something different if there is a separate `Sender:` header, which some systems automatically add when you override the default. If you need detailed control over these things, you will probably also need to separately configure your MTA (Postfix, Sendmail, what have you).

Comment: thanks it works, what is the difference between mailx and mail?

Comment: [It's complicated.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588035/874188) But I used `mailx` here by pure oversight. For `mailutils` on Ubuntu, I don't think it matters, out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

When system processes are sending email notifications and you don't have control over the mailx command line to add the From header, you can set a user's display name using

```
sudo chfn -f "*Display Name*" <user>
```

Emails from user will appear as being from *Display Name* in your email client.

Lastly, mailutils supports per-user configuration files, like ~/.mailx  You can set a user's email address there with

```
address {
  email-addr <email: address>;
};
```

Further explained in mailx's --config-help option. These techniques worked on Ubuntu LTS 22.04.