# Send email via mail command in python script

Tags: python, email, terminal

I'm trying to send text with multiple lines:

```
text = "This is a line 1
This is a line 2
This is a line 3"
```

in a python script with:

```
cmd = "echo {} | mail -s 'Test email' name@server.com".format(text)
os.system(cmd)
```

but I get an error because new lines are interpreted as commands:

```
sh: line 1: This: command not found
```

printing it out, it result in:

```
echo This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3 | mail -s 'Test email' name@server.com
```

I think the solution is simple, but I did not find any useful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that strings in the shell need to be quoted if they contain newlines or etc. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

But more fundamentally, you really don't want to use `os.system` here like this. Like its documentation already tells you, you generally want to prefer `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(
    ["mail", "-s", "Test email", "name@server.com"], 
    input=text, text=True, check=True)
```

or use `smtplib` to send email natively (or, conversely, don't use Python at all if all you need is a simple shell script, though you'd still need to fix the quoting then).

`mail` is poorly portable so if you haven't tested this on your system already, it might have additional problems.
Perhaps see also [How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line/48588035#48588035)

Comment: See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) and perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538