# Sending files as an attachment using Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file in the path mentioned below that is above 10M size. I need to write a shell script to send an email as an attachment only if the file size is less than 5M. If the file size is less than 10M size, I need to highlight only the path of the file in the email. Can anyone guide how to achieve this.

I tried the below script but it is giving - Message file too long warning.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/alb_test/alb/albt1/Source/alb/al/conversion/scripts
#Sending Email

ls *.xlsx -1 > test.txt
while read line
do
mailx -s "Test Email" -a ${line} -s "Attaching files less than 5 MB" abc@testmail.com,def@gmail.com << EOM

Hi, Sending the Files
EOM
done<test.txt
```

Comment: You did not put any file size check. Moreover, you say 10M (bytes I assume) in your question, but it is written 5MB in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clearly break down the **scenarios** that you need to handle, then code for those.  You need to distinguish between **4 file states**.

It helps for maintainability when you clearly define **parameters** for each one of those states, **separately**.

The placement of the "**-1**" in your **ls** statement is an error.  Also, to force one per line, there is no need to specify that, which is the default when directed to a file. "-1" is only needed for output to the terminal.

So here is the proposed solution to your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

filepath="/opt/alb_test/alb/albt1/Source/alb/al/conversion/scripts"

distro_list='abc@testmail.com,def@gmail.com'

THRESH_file=5000000
THRESH_path=10000000

SIGNATURE="
Me
MyPosition
MyEmail"

cd ${filepath}

#Sending Email

ls *.xlsx > test.txt

while read line
do
    if [ -s "${line}" ]
    then
        SIZE=$(stat --printf="%s" "${line}" )

        if [ ${SIZE} -lt ${THRESH_file} ]
        then
            SUBJECT="-s 'Attaching files under 5 MB'"
            MSG="Hi, Sending the undersized file."
            ATTACH="-a '${filepath}/${line}'"
        else
            if [ ${SIZE} -lt ${THRESH_path} ]
            then
                SUBJECT="-s 'File size at least 5 MB but less than 10 MB'"
                MSG="Hi, Sending the midsized file path:  '${line}' [${filepath}] "
                ATTACH=""
            else
                SUBJECT="-s 'File size at least 10 MB'"
                MSG="Hi, Sending the normal sized file."
                ATTACH="-a '${filepath}/${line}'"
            fi
        fi
    else
        SUBJECT="-s 'File is empty!'"
        MSG="File '${line}' is empty [${filepath}] ..."
        ATTACH=""
    fi

    echo -e "${MSG}\n${SIGNATURE}" |
        mailx ${SUBJECT} ${ATTACH} ${ditro_list}
done <test.txt
```

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and of course the temporary file is completely useless; simply `for line in *.xlsx` instead (though perhaps rename the variable to `file`) ... and [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: I used caps for variables here as a means to visibly highlight the repeated elements for each scenario.  I acknowledge the wisdom published in the link you provided.

Comment: @triplee, did you delete my earlier comment about using ls ?

Comment: Huh? Me? No. But if you left that comment after mine and somebody flagged it as redundant, a mod might have removed it. If a comment gets flagged as superfluous by multiple users it will be deleted automatically. But I can only speculate; I don't recall seeing a comment about that by you.

Comment: The use of string variables for options is also a problem for robustness; see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050